# pip install --user is installing to python/site-packages instead of python2.7/site-packages

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to get `pip install --user` to work with a prebuilt python system that is a little awkward.  We have it mostly working, but for some reason `pip install --user` is installing to `~/.casa/lib/python/site-packages` (where `.casa` replaces `.local` for this installation of python), but I can't understand how this is being set.

How does `pip install --user` select its directory?  What could I possibly have set to cause it to pick `python/site-packages` instead of `pythonX.Y/site-packages`?

The source code for the pip installer is at this package:
https://github.com/radio-astro-tools/casa-python
as far as I can tell, there is no situation in which `python/site-packages` occurs in that code; it is aways `pythonX.Y/site-packages` as it should be.

EDIT:
The pip I'm using is called with the following script.  Something in here is probably at fault, but I cannot determine what:

```
$HOME/.casa/bin/casa-python $HOME/.casa/bin/pip $* --user
```

which in turn is using `casa-python`, i.e. this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

INSTALLPATH=/Applications/CASA.app/Contents

PROOT=$INSTALLPATH/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
PBIND=$PROOT/MacOS
PLIBD=$PROOT/lib/python2.7
PPATH=$PBIND:$PLIBD:$PLIBD/plat-mac:$PLIBD/plat-darwin
PPATH=$PPATH:$PBIND/lib-scriptpackages:$PLIBD/lib-tk
PPATH=$PPATH:$PLIBD/lib-dynload:$PLIBD/site-packages
PPATH=$PPATH:$PLIBD/site-packages/Numeric:$PLIBD/site-packages/PyObjC
PPATH=$INSTALLPATH/Resources/python:$PPATH

export PYTHONUSERBASE=$HOME/.casa

export PYTHONHOME=$PROOT
export PYTHONPATH=/Users/adam/.casa/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PPATH
export PYTHONEXECUTABLE=$PROOT/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

export DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH="$INSTALLPATH/Frameworks"

exec -a pythonw $INSTALLPATH/MacOS/pythonw -W ignore::DeprecationWarning "$@"
```

Comment: What is the output of `which pip`?

Comment: `export PYTHONUSERBASE=$HOME/.casa` sets the root for the user base where packages installed with the `--user` option will go to. check [`site.py`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/648dcafa7e5f/Lib/site.py#l220) and [`sysconfig.py`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/648dcafa7e5f/Lib/sysconfig.py#l170) for more info

Comment: thanks @mata that's pointing me in the right direction; pip thinks I'm on a framework install and I am not.